# Does DBMS (e.g. of SQL SERVER 2008) use virtual memory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory

Or in other words ... . Does the DBMS somehow circumvent the OS Cache manager and acccess the memory directly OR it lets the OS do its job, behave as a normal process and use the concept of virtual memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual Memory is an indirection mechanism that map virtual addresses to physical addresses and the translation occurs in hardware layer through [PTEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Paged_virtual_memory). A process can refer and address **only** virtual memory. Only privileged execution (kernel) can address physical memory. I recommend you read a book on the subject, the classic being [Windows Internals](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708091326/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) by Russinovich/Solomon.

Your explanation is asking though a completely different question, whether OS 'Caches Manager' is circumvented. Virtual Memory is not a cache and there is never any sort of 'caching' in any discussion of a memory manager architecture (on *any* OS). It is not clear what 'cache manager' are you referring to. Does SQL Server do buffered IO (ie. uses OS file cache)? Generally no, see [How It Works: Bob Dorr's SQL Server I/O Presentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20151113155059/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/psssql/archive/2010/03/24/how-it-works-bob-dorr-s-sql-server-i-o-presentation.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I will have to look more into it. I have obviously mixed two different things together.